# Extended Stored Procedures impact on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamics-crm

We are gathering wait stats of SQL Server to troubleshoot intermittent issue of slowness related to database server. While doing so I came across wait type MSQL_XP it is consuming 39 wait percentage.When I researched more I find that it is coming due to extended events. Then using Activity Monitor I tried to find out which database executing extended stored procedure. So there are two stored procedure which are using sp_OAMEthod extended stored procedure.We have scheduled db job which which will poll after 15 min to table.So DB Job having sp which ultimately call's extended stored procedure.

So Is is true that extensive use of extended stored procedure causes performance problem in SQL Server.

I searched on database then I found bunch of extended stored procedure our DBA is using and they are scheduled.

Please let me know whether is it right to used to Extended Stored Procedure? Since Mircrosft has already deprecated usage of Extended Stored Procedure.

Also, We have Dynamics 365 MS-CRM,I searched in that database I found dozens of Extended stored procedure.

Comment: What are the Extended Stored Procedures doing?

Comment: 1. calling third party API and 2. Exporting records to file on demand (contains logic to transpose table) 3. Executing some dynamic SQL statement. Right now I figured out that much only